# Convert a parse ini to array / objects

Tags: php, html, html-table, ini, datatables-1.10

I'm using a program I made to scrape a file for text and parse the information into a ini file. I asked a question here earlier asking about `parse_ini_file` and why I could not use the indexes and someone gave me a way to loop through using this.

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("myfile.ini", true
foreach($ini_array as $key=>$value)
```

I then echo out the result `echo ($value['Username']) . " ";` and store it into the table. I have the table functioning link here, http://liveviewtest.byethost7.com/index.php but the plugin I'm using is not functioning as intended. The sorting does not work, and I'm wondering is it because the data type? http://www.datatables.net/manual/data tells you that the accepted data types are arrays, objects, and instances. My question is what would be the best way for me to convert this into one of these data types? I'm new to php / html so sorry if this is basic.

- Php File http://pastebin.com/VRUHLdMQ
- Ini File http://pastebin.com/yZsg16qA

Comment: plz show your myfile.ini and you have issue with datatables or parse_ini_file function

Comment: Edited the post, I'm having troubles with the column sorting on datatables, and I think its because of the data type I'm outputting.

Comment: The second parameter allows you separate ini by sections - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php. Since you have sections on your example you should start loop by sections and then by parameters in sections. Or change file for avoiding sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is being generated so PHP & Ini file are fine but HTML code you are generating is incorrect so either DataTable plugin or jQuery DOM parser is confused.

Please fix it and it should work fine.

[image]

- Put jquery+datatables js/css into `<head>` section.
- You use multiple `<tbody>` and you put `</tr>` after `</tbody>`

So basically you shoud put `echo "</tbody>";` outside loop so

```
echo "<tbody>"; // <<< HERE
foreach ($ini_array as $key => $value) {

    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo ($value[$getstats[$i]]);
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";        
}
echo "</tbody>";  // <<< HERE
```

---

> I'm wondering is it because the data type? http://www.datatables.net/manual/data tells you that the accepted data types are arrays, objects, and instances.

No, your code its fine as manual says `Data can be read from DOM`. You need arrays/objects/instances if you create table straight from javascript.

See below:

> ## DOM
>
> When DataTables starts up, it will automatically check the table it is operating on for data that already exists inside it and use it for the table (note that it will throw this data away if you pass in data using data or ajax to get new data!). This is the simplest method of using DataTables - working with a regular HTML table.
>
> Note that when using a DOM sourced table, DataTables will use arrays as the data source (see above) by default, although you could use the columns.data option to have it construct objects for the row data instead.

http://www.datatables.net/manual/data#DOM

Answer (score 0):

**Your table structure was not correct :**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- DataTables CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://liveviewtest.byethost7.com/DataTables-1.10.9/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://liveviewtest.byethost7.com/DataTables-1.10.9/media/js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables -->
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://liveviewtest.byethost7.com/DataTables-1.10.9/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://liveviewtest.byethost7.com/style.css">-->
    </head>


    <body>
                <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mytable').DataTable();
    });
</script>

        <table id="mytable" border ="1" style="width:100%">
            <thead>       
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Kills</th>
                    <th>Death Total</th>
                    <th>Suicides</th>
                    <th>Bears</th>
                    <th>Wolves</th>
                    <th>Helicopter</th>
                    <th>Falling</th>
                    <th>Cold</th>
                    <th>Explosions</th>
                    <th>Barricade</th>
                    <th>Player Deaths</th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>hpnotiq</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TacticalNuke735</td><td>1</td><td>12</td><td>12</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>.buckisM</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Mrs Phluffy</td><td>0</td><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>My buddy's goin'a jail</td><td>6</td><td>134</td><td>126</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td></tr><tr><td>marble</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Sir Joe</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>StryX</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Haroth</td><td>6</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Mr Sephy</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>4</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Solblade531</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Vavbro</td><td>3</td><td>14</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>Heisenberg</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>ã‚¢ãƒƒãƒ‘ãƒ¼ãŠã£ã±ã„</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Tallsockboy</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>CHAPYSIX</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Bik</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Totes MiGoats</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>Blunted Out'cha Mind</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Jubby</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>That0neGuy</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Nuclear</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>michaelswansey</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>kapiowai</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Kami</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Pika</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>WC Visuals</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>STUDNASTY</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>masternubb</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Bignubbb</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>BAAABBYNUBB</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Squirt</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Fluffy</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>| Albatross</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>inmate #42069 weston gayboy</td><td>10</td><td>9</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>isaiahyo</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>Vortex</td><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>General Pro</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Ecchi Sketchy</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>a e s t h e t i c</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>TheS1mpleGuy2Know</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>â™¥JaPierDoLeâ„¢</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>JaidenV</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>FaceEatingTumor</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Jfrisk</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Kilgore</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>chilmonik</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>chrishawsome</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>s4MPL3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>Dan Gleasak</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody> 
        
    </table>

</body>


</html>
```